# Get name of SimulationOutput variable "logsout" in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

To access the [`Simulink.SimulationOutput`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.simulationoutput-class.html) data stored in a variable named `logsout` by default for different simulations, I would like to retrieve that variable name from the Simulink model. How do I get it?

[image: Model Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the model parameter is `SignalLoggingName`. Try `get_param(model_name, 'SignalLoggingName')` to get the name of the variable.

You can usually type in the parameter prompt in the search box in configuration dialog and get the name of the corresponding parameter when the results show the description on the left and the name of the parameter on the right.

Comment: This is it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to try the following (which I tested):

1. Open your Simulink model and navigate to the subsystem where your signal is located.
2. Name your signal by clicking the signal wire and entering a name ('sig1' for example).
3. Right-click the signal wire, click Properties, and check the "log signal data" checkbox. Select 'Use signal name' for Logging name. Click OK.
4. At the command window, type ds = logsout.getElement('sig1')
5. Now the data should be accessible using ds.Values.Data and ds.Values.Time.

Hope it helps.